# Selenium Allure report data to show on Grafana dashboard

Tags: jenkins-plugins, pytest, prometheus, grafana, allure

I am trying to display the Allure report data on Grafana dashboard for my pytest (python + selenium) automation project. I am generating a allure report by given a run by jenkins. Need some heads up on how to show my jenkins run report to grafana. Is there any API/Plugin to send allure results to any time-series database (Influxdb or Prometheus)?

Answer (score 2):

Allure generates influxdb and prometheus files in export directory. I am about to write pytest 'plugin' that feeds this file to influxDB database. After that you set Grafana to pull from that database and show data.

Edit: I dont use selenium or jenkins, so for console pytest run I simply added this code (pytest hook) to conftest.py file:

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
from influxdb_client.client.write_api import SYNCHRONOUS


def pytest_terminal_summary(terminalreporter, exitstatus, config):
    influx_db_file = open('allure-html/export/influxDbData.txt', 'r')
    lines = influx_db_file.readlines()
    token = "MyToken"
    org = "MyOrg"
    bucket = "MyBucket"
    client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token=token)
    write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)

    for line in lines:
        write_api.write(bucket, org, line.strip())
```

This hook is executed when the pytest is finished. You have to pay attention to your influx url, and also your token, org and bucket values.

Comment: That's awesome @pera. Please update here once you done with 'plugin'.

Comment: I added code for my local pytest plugin (its a plugin hook that is just placed in conftest.py file). This code reads file that is exported by allure and feeds it to influx db line by line.